# What are these quotient spaces of sphere products homeomorphic to?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

For $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, consider the equivalence relation $(a,b) \sim(-a,-b)$ on $A \times B$. I'm trying to see what the quotient spaces of $S^2 \times S^1$ and $S^1 \times S^1$ by $\sim$ look like.

For the torus, I considered the fundamental polygon representation and divided it in four squares. Since $\sim$ identifies each square with the reflected square by the midpoint, by cut and pasting, I ended up with just a torus. This makes sense since I know that $S^1 \backslash \sim = S^1$, but I'm not sure that it is correct. For $S^2 \times S^1$ I don't know where to begin, and would appreciate any hint.

Comment: The first one looks right to me. For the second one, notice that $\mathbb{RP}^2 \equiv S^2/\langle x \sim -x ; x \in S^2\rangle$ and try constructing a homeomorphism with $\mathbb{RP}^2 \times S^1$, using the universal property of quotients.

Comment: So I would have to consider a function $g:S^2 \times S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^2 \times S^1$ such that $g(x,z)=g(x',z') \iff (x',z')=(-x,-z)$. I thought of $g$ defined as $g(x,z)=([x], z^2)$, but in this case $g(x,z)=g(-x,z)$, and for every function that I can think of the same happens. I'm starting to doubt they are homeomorphic.

Comment: In fact, I just realized that $\sim$ is not the product relation of the antipodal relations on both $S^1$ and $S^2$, so they are not homeomorphic.